# How to debug embedded javascript with 500 error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, api-design

**Context**
I would like to offer a bike rental companies (`shops`) the option to redirect guests to an online reservation process on my platform, so they can let customers make a reservation for a `bike` of the `shop`. *(e.g. online reservation process is just for their shop)*

**Current step**
My first step is to create an embedded javascript form (`form_availability`), where `shop` website visitors can select an `arrival`, `departure` date and subsequently see the available `bike_categories`. To clarify, I would like to show the initial form with arrival and departure options for tthat `shop`.

**Approach**

- I created an `api/v1/shops` (routes, controllers and views)
- I created an `embed.js` using webpacker:vue
- I implemented `<%= javascript_pack_tag "embed" %>` in my own app to test (url: `http://localhost:3000/en/shops/58/website_integration`)
- The `website` of the respective shop is `http://localhost:3000`

**Question**

It's the first time I'm doing this, and I get an error messages I don't know how to deal with/solve.

console

```
embed.js:23 GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/shops/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fen%2Fshops%2F3%2Fwebsite_integration/form_availability 500 (Internal Server Error)

./app/javascript/packs/embed.js @ embed.js:23
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
```

```
{type: "NoMethodError", message: "undefined method `url' for ["http://localhost:3000/en/shops/3/website_integration"]:Array", backtrace: Array(76)}

type: "NoMethodError"
message: "undefined method `url' for ["http://localhost:3000/en/shops/3/website_integration"]:Array"
backtrace: (76) ["/Users/robtuinte/code/Tumble25/camping_pms/app/models/shop.rb:41:in `block in <class:Shop>'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/active_record/relation.rb:288:in `instance_exec'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ib/active_record/relation.rb:288:in `_exec_scope'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…e_record/scoping/named.rb:186:in `block in scope'", "/Users/robtuinte/code/Tumble25/camping_pms/app/con…/v1/shops_controller.rb:16:in `form_availability'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…stract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…troller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ctive_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ct_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…nstrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ort/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…tive_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…r/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…r/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge….2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…on_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ction_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…b/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ction_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…n-js-3.5.1/lib/i18n/js/middleware.rb:14:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…s/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ck-2.0.7/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…5.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ck-2.0.7/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…5.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…atch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…0.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…tion_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge….2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…tch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ion_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…tion_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…patch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…b/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…spatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…s-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge….3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…b/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…b/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…lties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ion_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge….5.0/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…on_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ck-2.0.7/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…e/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…tion_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ction_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…acker/dev_server_proxy.rb:29:in `perform_request'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…s/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…uma-4.1.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…-4.1.0/lib/puma/server.rb:664:in `handle_request'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…-4.1.0/lib/puma/server.rb:467:in `process_client'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ma-4.1.0/lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…uma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'"]
__proto__:
```

logs

```
Started GET "/api/v1/shops/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fen%2Fshops%2F3%2Fwebsite_integration/form_availability" for ::1 at 2020-02-18 10:24:21 +0100
Processing by Api::V1::ShopsController#form_availability as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"http://localhost:3000/en/shops/3/website_integration"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**Code**

routes.rb

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :shops, only: [:show] do
        get :form_availability , on: :member
      end
    end
  end
```

controller/api/v1/shops_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::ShopsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def form_availability
    binding.pry
    @shop = Shop.by_url(params[:id])
    render "shops/form_availability"
  end
end
```

models

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bike_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bikes, through: :bike_categories
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy

  def self.by_url(url)
    binding.pry
    uri = url.split("?").first
    uri.sub!(/\/$/, '')

    where(website: uri)
  end
end

class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :bike
end

class Bike < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bike_category
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
end

class BikeCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  has_many :bikes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

javascript/packs/embed.js

```
let url = window.location.href


fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/shops/${encodeURIComponent(url)}/form_availability`,{
  headers: {accept: 'application/json'}
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

views/api/vi/shop/form_availability.json.jbuilder

```
json.extract! @shop, :id, :name, :slug, :description, :street, :street_number, :zipcode, :city, :country, :email, :phone, :website, :vat_number, :currency, :photo, :test_modus, :default_vat, :price_notation, :paytime, :billing_id, :default_shop_language, :default_age_table, :inv_pay_deadline
```

Comment: This may help you - https://www.exceptionalcreatures.com/bestiary/NoMethodError.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, `@park` was an array.